# Conditionally format cells based on date variables returned to TEXT() function

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have created a calendar in Excel, for which I am having trouble formatting a cell relative to it's representation of the current day of the year:

3/12/2014

```
MARCH                       
S   M   T   W   T   F   S
                        1
2   3   4   5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20  21  22
23  24  25  26  27  28  29
30  31
```

What I'm trying to do is get Excel to automatically fill the cell in red and format the font to white, bold text if the number in that cell matches the number returned by the function `=TEXT(A1,"dd")`, where the contents of cell A1 is populated by the function =TODAY().

It also must check to make sure that the value in cell B3 matches the value returned by function `=TEXT(A1,"mmmm")`. If not, the twelfth day of every month would be highlighted.

In this case, with today being March 12th, I would want the cell containing the number `12` above to be effected by conditional formatting.

I have tried using various formulas to compare the cell values with date return strings, but nothing has worked.

Is this even possible to do with a conditional formatting formula?

Comment: The solution depends on the exact cell contents of your calendar - the days look like numbers but they may be formatted dates or text - if you select the MARCH 12 cell and format as general what do you see in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option that works for me:

[image]

The conditional formatting is based on whether the following formula evaluates to true

```
=AND(MONTH($A$1)=3,DAY($A$1)=A5)
```

and applies to `=$A$5:$G$10`.

---

Here's the exact procedure in order to establish this conditional formatting:

1. Click on cell A5.
2. Select Conditional Formatting > New Rule
3. Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4. Format; specify the Font and Fill according to your requirements
5. Specify the rule description to "Format values where this formula is true:"

   ```
   =AND(MONTH($A$1)=3,DAY($A$1)=A5)
   ```

   [image]

   Note the use of `$` to fix the reference to `$A$1` where you're entering your date, yet only using an unconstrained `A5` for the cell you're in.
6. Expand the conditional formatting to apply to a larger area:

   ```
   =$A$5:$G$10
   ```

   [image]
7. Click OK.

---

This scales just as well to an annual calendar where you would define 12 different conditional formats:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do. Start with your spreadsheet like this:

[image: initial spreadsheet]

Basically it contains the actual dates in each of the cells, with each date being calculated by the previous date plus one.

Then format the cells to be `d`, but not by using the formula `Text(A1,"d")`. The heading simply gets formatted as `mmmm`.

Then it is an easy matter of applying conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=RC=TODAY()
```

Where `RC` is the current cell you are applying the format on. Then copy and paste formatting over the entire calendar.

I then get this:

[image: Answer]